# Can FirebaseDatabase code be converted to Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create add a cart to the restaurant application using Firebase and Riverpod,
so can it be converted to firestore or it's completely different structure?

I saw some youtube videos where the guy created a cart model, besides this code below:

addToCart function:

```html
void addToCart(GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey, ProductsModel drinkModel){
    var cart = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("Cart").child("Unique_USER_ID");
    cart.child(drinkModel.key).once().then((value){
        if (snapshot.exists) {
          // Data found at the specified document path
          var cartModel = CartModel.fromJson(json.decode(json.encode(snapshot.value)));
          cartModel.quantity+=1;
          cartModel.totalPrice = double.parse(drinkModel.price);

        } else {
        }
      });
    }
```

**ProductsModel.dart**

```html
class ProductsModel {
  String? key;
  String? description;
  bool? featured;
  int? price;
  String? title;
  String? urlImage;

  ProductsModel(
      {this.key,this.description, this.featured, this.price, this.title, this.urlImage});

  ProductsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    key = json['key'];
    description = json['description'];
    featured = json['featured'];
    price = json['price'];
    title = json['title'];
    urlImage = json['urlImage'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['key'] = this.key;
    data['featured'] = this.featured;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['urlImage'] = this.urlImage;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Here is my cartModel.dart file **(in case you need it):**

```html
class CartModel {
  String? key;
  String? name;
  String? image;
  String? price;
  int? quantity;
  double? totalPrice;

  CartModel(
      {required this.key,
      required this.name,
      required this.image,
      required this.price,
      required this.quantity,
      required this.totalPrice});

  CartModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    key = json['key'];
    name = json['name'];
    image = json['image'];
    price = json['price'];
    quantity = json['quantity'] as int;
    totalPrice = double.parse(json['totalPrice']);
  }

  Map<String,dynamic> toJson(){
    final Map<String,dynamic> data = new Map<String,dynamic>();
    data['key'] = this.key;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['image'] = this.image;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['quantity'] = this.quantity;
    data['totalPrice'] = this.totalPrice;

    return data;
  }

}
```

Comment: Data modeling can be very different between the two.  It's not just a matter of porting code.

Answer (score 0):

As Doug commented, the data model between Firebase's Realtime Database and Firestore is quite different and there is no automatic conversion between them. You will have to define your own data model for Firestore, and then port your code over.

For example, you might end up with a `Products` collection and a `Cart` collection, and the code for mapping between the data in the database and your classes will be similar as what you have now.

If you get stuck on a specific piece of the conversion, you can always post a new question with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and concrete question for that.

Comment: actually I'm stuck with           var cartModel = CartModel.fromJson(json.decode(json.encode(snapshot.value))); do we handle json data in firestore , also do we add cart list to user collection ? or the opposite

Comment: The `json` variable in your code is `Map<String, dynamic> json`, so it's a `Map`. And both Firestore and RTDB expose key-value pairs in the data as maps, so this code should be pretty portable. If something doesn't work, edit your question to show exactly what you did for Firestore, and what error you got.